# How to set up email notification when task scheduler completes "with return code..."

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

How can I setup an email notification to myself when task scheduler not failed but completed

> with return error code...

Again, log file doesn't say Error, it says

> Action completed

The only difference difference between truly successful completion and not in a log file is

> with return code ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged powershell, you could do something like this.

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Some log name'} |
    Where-Object message -match 'with return code (?<ErrorCode>.+?)\.' |
        Foreach-Object {
            # Send mail code here
            Send-MailMessage ...

            # Some info that may be useful
            $_.TaskDisplayName
            $_.TimeCreated
            $_.MachineName
            $matches.ErrorCode

        }
```